# Is there an alternative to using List<string[]>?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm using:

```
List<string[]>
```

which works, but just feels so wrong! Does anyone have any correct more up date ways to achieve this or is it not wrong? I have tried the following, which works but also feels wrong:

```
List<List<string>>
```

For any moaners out there, my definition of wrong is hacky, out of date, old code, over complicated code, etc

Thanks

Edit:

Sorry guys, I forgot to mention the list length is un-known so it's likely to be large list with a non specified number of items, each array will consist of around 10-20 items

Comment: Lists and arrays are different beasts. Are you sure you need inner lists (i.e. can they shrink or grow)?

Comment: Depends entirely on what you're actually trying to do. Neither of those are in of themselves 'wrong' - it's all a matter of context.

Comment: If you're storing an array or arrays of strings you could do string[][]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness Not if he wants the outer dimension to be able to grow/shrink.  This is a pattern that I see a lot when reading/writing to CSV files.  The inner dimension is fixed, the outer dimension is not.

Comment: What are you using it for?

Comment: There's no right or wrong answer here; it depends entirely on what you're doing with your list of string arrays. Can you provide more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I've used `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` on occasion, when it was the right structure. It is no different from your examples.

Comment: a majority of the comments here are valid but I think that without seeing how you are using it currently in regards to showing your Data or code sample then you will end up with a lot of educated guesses in regards to comments and best practices

Comment: What strikes me about both is the amount of mutability inherent in the system. Both the outer collection and each inner collection can be modified; the difference between `List<string[]>` and `List<List<string>>` to my mind is that the latter exposes more mutability because the inner lists can change length as well as contents. Is that desirable? I would be more inclined towards `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`. But as others have said, without knowing the context it is hard to say which is better.

Comment: Since it sounds like the inner arrays can vary in size, I would lean towards the `List<List<string>>` option. There's nothing "hacky" about such a data type. It's actually quite common, in my experience.

Comment: It depends on how you view it. If you are used to using, say tables, or something similar, then, the idea of a list of lists or list or arrays may look not look very intuitive. But, as has been mentioned, there is nothing wrong with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything *wrong* with either of them, in the general case.  There are certainly specific cases where one or the other may not be appropriate, but without any details there is no way of knowing whether this is an appropriate usage.

It's certainly not a pattern that you would globally consider bad.  There's simply no reason for that to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would put

```
List<string>
```

inside a class then use

```
List<Class>
```

Comment: Why?  What's the advantage of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

> the list length is un-known

If you don't know the length why not use `List<List<string>>`?

As mentioned before it's neither wrong nor hacky or overcomplicated. It's exactly what you need. A list of unknown length that contains lists of strings.

Comment: The length of the outer dimension is unknown; the length of the inner dimension may not be unknown.  If it's fixed, then a `List<string[]>` is acceptable (although not really *better*, either is fine).